# anaconda installation, not getting the question 'do you accept the terms?'

Tags: installation, anaconda3, ubuntu-20.10

while installing anaconda in ubuntu 22.10, i followed this steps below:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install curl -y
cd /tmp
curl --output anaconda.sh https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
sha256sum anaconda.sh
bash anaconda.sh

every thing was smooth, but after reading all the terms, i didn't get the question that asks if i do accept the license terms, and the installation doesn't start i've waited a fair amount of time but nothings happen. How do i fix this problem?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Just press the key <kbd>Q</kbd>.

I hope this will work for you.